# how to distribute hybrid app outside appstore

Tags: mobile, mobilesdk, ios

I'm sure lots of users here have built apps using the Mobile SDK. How are you distributing them? I've built a hybrid-remote app to go with our managed package. I don't want the app to be available in the appstore but it will need to be provided to all of our package customers. Is the iOS developer enterprise program my only option for iOS?

I understand the Android version is much easier where you can just provide a link to the app for installation. Is that correct?

Comment: https://www.salesforce.com/form/demo/platform-privateappex-demo.jsp?d=70130000000tboG&internal=true&nc=70130000000tboB&videoId=1m7U3gRZ-_c .This looks an option

Comment: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N3000000B4VlZEAV&d=70130000000tboL&internal=true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [wrote another answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/37154/209) along these lines that explores a few options.

tl;dr - You are almost certainly better-served, and your users will have a far superior install and update experience, if you list on the public app store.

Why do you not want to list publicly? I can see only a few good reasons why you wouldn't (and some of those reasons aren't good at all, like your app using private APIs).

Comment: Thanks, thats a very comprehensive answer. My concern with either app store or b2b is the review. What do you mean by private APIs? My app is hybrid-remote (not a lot of content in the app itself) and uses javascript remoting.

Comment: I think your concerns are misplaced. Consider also that Apple's review will check for bugs, signup experience, functionality, and (maybe) accessibility, and you'll surely benefit from their feedback. Sounds like you are not using private APIs - these are iOS APIs that are not included in public headers/docs and will cause your app to be rejected.

Answer (score 1):

Apple allows three types of installs. The first type is the AppStore. The second is ad hoc installs. This mode is limited to 100 devices. The third may be of interest to you. It's the b2b program, in which only authorized clients can see or install the app. It's separate from the main AppStore, sort of quasi-private.

Look here for more info. https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/distribute.html

Android apps are definitely easier to distribute.

Comment: ugh, it still has to go through app review in the b2b one. the SF private app exchange isn't an alternative to any of these is it?

Comment: Nope. Apple really has an iron grip on their devices.

Answer (score 1):

Public distribution will save you the most headaches. Apple's processes for Enterprise are of no use in this case, and although I've not used their B2B program I suspect it'll have more than it's fair share of caveats and complexities like the Enterprise route.

If your app requires a SFDC login then it's already protected against the general public. If you need to make it available to only select customers, you could just ensure that the target org has a managed package installed on first login, and use the LMA to control that side of things.