# App iOS and Android on Appexchange

Tags: appexchange, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, connected-apps

I have a simple hybrid app which can be published both for iOS and Android.

The salesforce part is just the "Connected App" (the apps use only standard fields and such).

I would like to publish this app on the appExchange, but it is unclear to me how to procede, on the AppExchange publication page I can select only salesforce components (which is just the connected app..)

I was unable to find a guide on how to do it, do you have experience with this scenario (which should be pretty common!)

Thanks,
T.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've answered your own question, no? Your package on the appexchange includes your connected app definition, plus a link to the iOS App Store or Google Play Store where users can install your app.

**Edit**: My note above is inaccurate; I believe there should be only one Connected App definition for all orgs. Given that your app has no custom components of its own, there is nothing to install in target orgs. See [my previous answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/37130/salesforce-private-app-exchange-distribution/37154#37154) on branding mobile apps for multiple customers. You definitely don't need multiple versions of your app.

**Edit the second**: With no package and nothing to install in target orgs, an interesting question is whether the Appexchange will allow you to have a listing in the first place. Obviously I think they should, but you might be best off checking with the partner/ISV team directly on this. I can't imagine they haven't been through this exact use case previously for mobile apps.

Comment: In the app there is a configuration json, in this json you need to put a string which is a token of the connected app. If every org has new connected apps, I should prepare an app for every orgs! Do you have experience with this directly? If it was up to me, that token is just a string to get a name for the app for login purposes so there would be no need for every org to have it's own connected app. Maybe is it just like this?

Comment: No, that is not accurate - there should only be one connected app for all orgs. I've edited my answer above.